# SVG graph and Javascript: Which is the best way to add animation to and SVG file?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm new at coding.

I'm studying the way to make an animated portfolio like Sean Halpin or Stephanie Walter one. I want to put a face, in which, blinking eyes and a moving the mouth would be the animated elements. Basically, I want to play with the visibility of the closed eyes and open mouth. As an example, I drew a face as follows:

```html
<svg id="Capa_1" data-name="Capa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 429 429">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #fff;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="face">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M611,608.5a214,214,0,1,1,151.32-62.68A212.6,212.6,0,0,1,611,608.5Z" transform="translate(-396.46 -180)" />
    <path d="M611,181a212.9,212.9,0,1,1-83.1,16.78A212.11,212.11,0,0,1,611,181m0-1c-118.46,0-214.5,96-214.5,214.5S492.5,609,611,609s214.5-96,214.5-214.5S729.43,180,611,180Z" transform="translate(-396.46 -180)" />
  </g>
  <g id="eyes">
    <g id="eye_r">
      <circle class="cls-1" cx="319.15" cy="128.63" r="48.5" />
      <path d="M715.61,260.62a48,48,0,1,1-48,48,48.06,48.06,0,0,1,48-48m0-1a49,49,0,1,0,49,49,49,49,0,0,0-49-49Z" transform="translate(-396.46 -180)" />
    </g>
    <g id="iris_r">
      <circle cx="319.15" cy="128.63" r="19" />
    </g>
    <g id="eye_l">
      <circle class="cls-1" cx="109.85" cy="128.63" r="48.5" />
      <path d="M506.32,260.62a48,48,0,1,1-48,48,48.06,48.06,0,0,1,48-48m0-1a49,49,0,1,0,49,49,49,49,0,0,0-49-49Z" transform="translate(-396.46 -180)" />
    </g>
    <g id="iris_l">
      <circle cx="109.85" cy="128.63" r="19" />
    </g>
    <line id="closed_eye_l" class="cls-2" x1="62.04" y1="128.5" x2="158.04" y2="128.5" />
    <line id="closed_eye_r" class="cls-2" x1="270.69" y1="128.23" x2="366.69" y2="128.23" />
  </g>
  <g id="closed_mouth">
    <ellipse cx="214.5" cy="309" rx="108.5" ry="11.5" />
    <path d="M611,478c29.08,0,56.41,1.25,77,3.51,30.68,3.38,31,7.32,31,7.49s-.35,4.11-31,7.49C667.37,498.75,640,500,611,500s-56.41-1.25-77-3.51c-30.69-3.38-31-7.32-31-7.49s.35-4.11,31-7.49c20.55-2.26,47.88-3.51,77-3.51m0-1c-60.2,0-109,5.37-109,12s48.8,12,109,12,109-5.37,109-12-48.8-12-109-12Z" transform="translate(-396.46 -180)" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

So, I thought three ways to do this:

1. Place the svg inside an  tag, calling then a function that takes into consideration the loading of the file. An example of what I'm saying is found in the following resource: https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/javascript/, in the "External SVG + External JavaScript" part. It didn't work. The contentDocument ALWAYS returns "null".

In my example, it would be:

HTML:

```
<object id="face" data="path/to/face.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var svgObject = document.getElementById('face').contentDocument;
    var svg = svgObject.getElementById('closed_eye_r');
    svg.style.visibility="hidden";
  });
</script>
```

2. Inline SVG - call a "transform" property. Sean Halpin does it but I'm not sure what he does.

HTML: https://www.seanhalpin.design/
JS: https://www.seanhalpin.design/js/scripts.js

3. Inline SVG, use getElementById and apply functions to animate the internal parts of the SVG file.

Questions:

a. Is Inline SVG a good practice?
b. Which is the best way to animate an SVG?

I hope to have been clear. Let me know if something is not well presented, I want to learn to edit questions in order to make them as clear as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for SMIL animation